# Multiple activity on screen of Android?

Tags: android, listactivity, mapactivity

So the problem is I need to create a screen where I have a map and a list under it ,
but to have a map I have a :

```
 public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity{}
```

to have a list i have :

```
class MyListActivity extends ListActivity{}
```

since there is no multiple inheritance ,what is the correct way to do this?
Does Android have any Interface for this ?
How would you do this?

So i did it like this:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setAdapter((new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES)));
```

with the layout xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="214dp"
    android:apiKey="0FKRDCDlhIYZGYtZdLy5-gDjxF3Q25T7_RIortA"
    android:clickable="true" />

  <ListView
        android:id = "@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLay>
```

but it keep dying any ideea how to start debugging i'm a bit new to Android development

Answer (score 4):

Use only MapActivity.....You can Display listview Without ListActivity ,but Cant Mapview without MapActivity...

```
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity{

}
```

**I mean display listview using**

```
<Listview android:id = "@+id/mylist"..../>
```

**and you get ,**

```
ListView listview =(ListView)findviewByid(R.id.mylist);  
listview.setAdapter(youradapter);
```