# android call public class in another public class in the same activity

Tags: android

```
package xx.xx.xx

public class Mappingactivity extends MapActivity{

}

public class Listactivity extends ListActivity{

}
```

how to call the Listactivity inside Mappingactivity? coz im trying to get the map view and the list view on the same activity. or else is there any other way?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't call another class(Activity)

you just add `ListView` and `MapView` in layout file.and `extends MapActivity`.

`Create object of ListView.and setAdapter to it.Its not compulsory if you want to show listview then must extend ListActivity.`

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749775/776244)

Comment: when i use it... i can not use setListAdapter(adapter); it does not work.

Comment: `listview.setAdapter(objAdapter);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make another class for the listactivity and then import it in this one.Then you will be able to use it all over the activity.
Use :
     import xx.xx.xx.listactivity

Whatever name you gave to the class.